# How to PopUp a keyboard on runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

Hey i'am building apps with flash builder 4.6 for mobile development and on the runtime the keyboard did not appear.
So what to do to show the keyboard ?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read Adobe's doc [Open a soft keyboard in a mobile Flex application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html)?

[image]